# Grouping by a custom column composed of multiple actual columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to display location info constituted by multiple columns in the DB but then I need to group it by the ID. The solution I've got is to list the constituting columns as groupees in the following way.

```
select 
  Id,
  Name,
  Here + ' and ' + There as Location,
  count(*) as Count
from KnownStuff
group by Id, Name, Here, There
```

However, I'd like to know if there a more like-a-bossy way to group by that column, i.d. something along the lines of this.

```
group by Id, Name, Location
```

Or, even better (although, based on my googlearching, I'm pretty sure that it's not possible), I'd like to **exclude** all the other columns except for *Id* from the grouping constraints. In some cases I'll use *sum* or some other aggregating function but it'd be nice to just tell the server not to bother And if there are non-identical occurrences, then so be it - let it crash, burn, cry or lie - after all, it's **my** problem that I wrote a faulty script.

So:

1. Is there a like-a-bossy approach to grouping a custom column?
2. Is there a bite-me-in-the-ass-laterish approach to make it easier for now?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? :)

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I want to know from someone savvy on SQL if there's a more pro-like way to achieve grouping than what I did. And also, if there's a hack-around to make the development process easier.

Comment: "I want to display location info constituted by multiple columns in the DB but then I need to group it by the ID." What is the expected result of grouping location by ID? You may choose Max(location) or Min(location) for example.

Comment: @Serg Yes? I feel that I'm missing your point. I **do know** that those will be the same anyway and even if they wouldn't be for some weird reason, I'm not concerned by that. I'll be grouping them away anyway - I'm just looking for a more convenient syntax than grouping explicitly by all the columns instead of *Location*.

Comment: @Serg Oh, I didn't see your edit at first. The reason to grouping is that I want to know how many reported reading we have for each customer. Listing the location is just a bonus info that doesn't need to be reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the query up in a derived table. Do `GROUP BY` it's result:

```
select id, name, location, count(*)
from
(
select 
  Id,
  Name,
  Here + ' and ' + There as Location,
from KnownStuff
)
group by Id, Name, location
```

Comment: I was hoping for a trick to force the server to *magically* be aware that grouping by *Location* means grouping by each of its columns. I'm guessing there's no luck there. Your answer is technically correct so I'll be accepting it in a short while. How about (2)?

Comment: Derived tables is the trick when doing group by on other things than table columns. ANSI SQL allows nothing but columns in the group by clause. (Some products however allow result column aliases too, like location in you case.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sql server  specifically has another convinient option, APPLY, to deal with intermediate calculations.

Answer (score 1):

May be encapsulating the Select with a [SQL CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) expression can be a way

```
;with cte as (
select 
  Id,
  Name,
  Here + ' and ' + There as Location,
  --count(*) as Count
from KnownStuff
--group by Id, Name, Here, There
)
select
    Id, Name, Location, count(*) as [Count]
from cte
group by Id, Name, Location
```

This is actually like a sub-query

Answer (score 1):

You can add computed column to your table.

```
alter table knownstuff add Location as (Here + ' and ' + There)
```

Computed columns are not stored physically. Then you can rewrite the query as:

```
select 
  Id,
  Name,
  Location,
  count(*) as Count
from KnownStuff
group by Id, Name,Location
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying that the table won't be affected although we perform *alter* on it? ALso, what's the thingy at the end of your alter statement? Typo?

Comment: I mean table size will not increase after you added this column in your table it is a virtual column it will get computed each time when select statement runs,don't use that column in where clause it will convert that in to full table scan